# R: Interactive RcppGSL use

Tags: r, makefile, rcpp

I am trying to use `RcppGSL` on a 64-bit Windows machine, but feel that there are some nuances of the `make` variables that I am not understanding.

Here is what I tried:
1. *Installed* GSL from binaries available [here](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/Rtools/goodies/multilib/local300.zip) in a new directory I created in the top-level R installation directory.
2. Updated the environment variables to include a new variable `LIB_GSL` to point to the folder where I unzipped GSL.
3. Create a set of files in a new directory:
- example1.cpp
- Makevars.win

Here is what each of the files looks like.

### example1.cpp

The `example1.cpp` file is the basic column norms function that is included as an example in the `RcppGSL` package itself:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppGSL)]]
#include <RcppGSL.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector colNorm(Rcpp::NumericMatrix sM) {

    RcppGSL::matrix<double> M(sM);   // create gsl data structures from SEXP
    int k = M.ncol();
    Rcpp::NumericVector n(k);       // to store results 

    for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        RcppGSL::vector_view<double> colview = gsl_matrix_column (M, j);
        n[j] = gsl_blas_dnrm2(colview);
    }

    M.free();       // important: GSL wrappers use C structure
    return n;               // return vector  
}
```

### Makevars.win

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I$(LIB_GSL)/include -I../inst/include 
PKG_LIBS=-L$(LIB_GSL)/lib/x64 -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

### Question:

However, when I `sourceCpp` the `example1.cpp` file, it gives me the following output:

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('example53[RcppGSL].cpp')
g++ -m64 -I"F:/PROGRA~1/r/R-31~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -IF:/programming/r/R-3.1.1/GSL/include     -I"F:/programming/r/R-3.1.1/library/Rcpp/include" -I"F:/programming/r/R-3.1.1/library/RcppGSL/include"  -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c example53[RcppGSL].cpp -o example53[RcppGSL].o
g++ -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o sourceCpp_9705.dll tmp.def example53[RcppGSL].o -LF:/programming/r/R-3.1.1/GSL/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -LF:/PROGRA~1/r/R-31~1.1/bin/x64 -lRlapack -LF:/PROGRA~1/r/R-31~1.1/bin/x64 -lRblas -lgfortran -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LF:/PROGRA~1/r/R-31~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
f:/programming/r/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgsl
f:/programming/r/rtools/gcc-4.6.3/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgslcblas
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp("example53[RcppGSL].cpp") : 
  Error occurred building shared library.
```

Now, I know that my files are actually in `-L$(LIB_GSL)/lib/x64`, but the linker is looking in `-L$(LIB_GSL)/lib` (this is reflected in my `Makevars.win` as well), hence is not able to find `libgsl` or `libgslcblas`. How can I enforce that this is the `PKG_LIBS` passed to `cppSource` instead of whatever the default is.

My current workaround is to copy everything from `-L$(LIB_GSL)/lib/x64` to `-L$(LIB_GSL)/lib` but not happy with that solution.

Answer (score 1):

The `Makevars.win` is not used by `sourceCpp()`.

When I do this here on Linux, things just work as expected:

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/coln.cpp")   # where coln.cpp is what you have above
R> colNorm(matrix(1:16,4,4))
[1]  5.47723 13.19091 21.11871 29.08608
R>
```

What is used for you on Windows is determined at package load time via the file `R/inline.R` in the package sources, and it reflects what the `LIB_GSL` has.

Maybe the line `gsl_libs <- sprintf( "-L%s/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas", LIB_GSL )` needs a correction and we need to append `/x64` for you?  Could you debug that?

Comment: Well, the Windows binary package does not have the sources (presumably you are asking me to look in "library/RcppGSL/R/"). I will try downloading the source and make the edits. PS. `install_github("eddelbuettel/rcppgsl")` gives a very weird error on Windows.

Comment: I don;t use devtools as I have a github repo. And you may as well use the released CRAN sources though there does not seem to be a difference right now.